# bs-tooltip restricts two way data binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap

I am trying a simple code with angular strap's bootstrap tooltip. I am seeing that AngularJs data binding is not working when `bs-tooltip` is used.

**Bind not working**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name1" data-trigger="focus" data-type="success" data-title="something" bs-tooltip> {{ name1 }}
```

**Bind works**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name"> {{ name }}
```

**[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/OEpMTsAnzDSJ26hhV7LK?p=preview)**

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like angular-strap creates a child scope for the input control, but `{{name1}}` is located to its parent scope. If you inspect the HTML, you will see `ng-scope` in class, while the second input control does not.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$parent.name1"
   data-trigger="focus" data-type="success" data-title="something" bs-tooltip="" 
   class="ng-valid ng-scope ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse">
```

My simple solution is to add a `$parent.` prefix to the variable. It works as

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$parent.name1" 
   data-trigger="focus" data-type="success" data-title="something" bs-tooltip> {{ name1 }}
```

Comment: Thanks, works for now. But it looks like an issue ain't it?

Comment: You might raise an issue at github. I don't strongly think it is a bug, because directive might create scope on demand. You have to live with the fact.

Comment: If you think the answer helps you, please up vote my answer and accept it. Thanks.

Comment: One tip by the way, you can write `bs-tooltip="something"``.